# Can I check App Store for updates programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Mac App Store manages all apps updates (at least the ones that are download from it) and system updates, and it shows a notification if there is something new. Is there a way I can programmatically check if App Store is showing a notification, using Objective-C? I wanna warn the user if system could be in a unsafe state, and softwares out of date could lead to it. And I can't find an easy way to check all softwares versions, including the OS, that wouldn't be checking App Store. Any idea of how could a do it? In addition would it be aligned with Apple policy? I don't know if a app can check others app info (I read Mac App Store Review Guidelines and I couldn't finde anything about).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you release and update that could potentially be in an unsafe state? You should just test your app properly before each release.

Comment: I don't want to check my own app. I wanna check all the others apps installed, including the OS. And I don't wanna update them, I just wanna show the user that system could be in a unsafe state.

Comment: You want to warn a user not to download your own update if they are running a version of IOS that is not compatible with your app.. ? - In my first comment I just meant that you should make sure your update is compatible instead of faffing around making checks after an update is launched..

Comment: I don't wanna force the user to make decision based on my app version, if it runs in the newest OS version or not. I just wanna warn him/her that some softwares in his system are out of date, or his/her OS is out of date, what could lead the system to be in a unsafe state (unsafe I mean vulnerable to bugs, attacks, etc). Am I wrong when trying to do it?

Comment: humm, ''I wanna warn the user if system could be in a unsafe state, and softwares out of date could lead to it'' there are no unsafe software for the system on App Store. in addition, there is no way to check all the apps on the App Store, unless you download all of the app id's of the apps on the app store and write a method so long it will take about a year (estimated time not actual) to write. and at last, why would you want to check the update of all apps when it is usually available by apple through notification as you already know.

Comment: For example, if user downloaded an antivirus from App Store and didn't update it anymore. User has no knowledge in security at all. A new antivirus version is released, user doesn't download. And still believe users system it's safe. So in this case, warn the user would be good, right? And about checking the update, I don't want to do it, I just want to get the information that App Store already has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way programatically in the iOS SDK to check whether the OS or an app has any updates available, sans jailbreaking.

What you could do though, is keep track in your app what iOS version it's running on and roll your own web service that tells the app what the current version of iOS is (which you'll be updating as updates happen to iOS are released), that way you'll be able to tell users to update.

Bottom line, though, there's no need to do that, as iOS already nags people into updating, and your app adding to that nag probably won't make them update faster.

As for letting the user know that they're updates out for other apps, you could theoretically use the [iTunes Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to get that data on all of the apps out there, but you won't be able to get the version of each app the user has on their device at the moment. And even then with automatic updates to the apps now being the norm, the user would just be confused by your app nagging him to update. And that's if you could write up the web services for that and keep them up to date with all of the updates, as it'll have to constantly crawl all of the apps in the AppStore, which is just not feasible.

Edit:

Ok, so you edited it to the Mac App Store, no idea about that, but it's probably just as hard.

Comment: Has to be the best answer here. Couldn't be any clearer.

Comment: I don't want to check the updates by myself, I want to take the information given by Mac App Store. If is that what you are saying: "There is no how take the information from Mac App Store" them I accept the answer. Is that what you mean?